# How to make http redirect in node red?

Tags: node-red

I need to redirect to another url. I am using nodered to request a url, then getting the username and password, checking them in a cloudant database and after veryfing that they are exist, i need to redirect to another /home.
Is there a node to redirect?. I tried with http request node, but it just get the response in json or binary not redirecting the url. How to redirect in nodered?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Do you mean the HTTP-in/HTTP-out nodes not the HTTP-request node? The HTTP-in/out nodes allow Node-RED to handle incoming HTTP requests, the HTTP-request node is for making calls to other servers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to trigger a redirect you need to do two things:

1. set the status code of the response to the appropriate value
2. set the `location` header to the url to redirect to.

Referring to the help for the `HTTP Response` node, you can set the status code either directly in the HTTP Response node, or by setting `msg.statusCode` on the message to pass the node.

The value you set it to will depend on the type of redirection you want to do - whether its a permanent or temporary redirect.

For example, a common pattern is to redirect a POST request that creates a resource to a GET request of the new resource. That would be a temporary redirect using `303` as the status code.

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) is a good reference for the different types of redirect code.

To set the `Location` header, you can again, either hardcode it in the HTTP Response node, or set it under the `msg.headers` property.

For example, a Function node such as the following would do it:

```
msg.statusCode = 303;
msg.headers = {
    Location: "https://google.com"
}
delete msg.payload;
return msg;
```

You could also use a Change node to do the same:

[image]

Comment: last line of example for Function node should be `return msg;`