# How Node-red http response redirect to an URL with msg.payload as a query string

Tags: node-red

I am new to Node-red and try to use the http response node to redirect a page with query strings.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845797/how-to-make-http-redirect-in-node-red) and successfully used the header location via change node (I also tried directly set the attribute in http response node) to redirect to an URL. My goal is to redirect to a website with msg.payload as a query string. 
My msg.payload contains a simply JSON object like

```
{"id":"1", "condition":2, "nset":3}
```

I have tried setting the location as `http://[redirect_website]/getinfo?{{payload}}` but I was redirected to `http://[redirect_website]/getinfo?{{payload}}` instead of `http://[redirect_website]/getinfo?id=1&condition=2&nset=3`. Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60647454/edit) the question to explain where/how you have tried to set the header. s it using a function node or a change node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably going to have to build the query string yourself.

So using a function node to set the `location` header it would be something like:

```
msg.statusCode = 303;
msg.headers = {
    Location: "https://example.com/getinfo?id=" +
    msg.payload.id + "&condition=" +
    msg.payload.condition + "&nset=" +
    msg.payload.nset;
}
delete msg.payload;
return msg;
```

This code is only safe if all the values are numbers, if some of the values are strings then you need to make sure you URLEncode them before adding them.

If things get more complicated them you should probably add the `querystring` module ([doc](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)) to the global context (how to add modules to the global context [doc](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions#loading-additional-modules)) and use this in the function node to generate the query string in one go from the `msg.payload` object.

Comment: Thanks, @hardillb ! After correcting a typo (a `+` was missed between `msg.payload.condition` and `"&nset="`) and change `return` to `return msg`, it works! The `querystring` module is also a nice thing to know.